# SPLUL90_AT08 Laser Diode issue

Tags: diodes, laser-diode

Our team now evaluate laser diodes for making LIDAR

At first, we bought SPL UL90_A T08 from digikey
and used lmg1025-q1evm (Ti) board to drive the LD.

We drive Forward direction with 11V (As Datasheet of LD says that)

You can see image below link

**schematic**

[image: schematic]

**View**
[image: View]

Considering that laser diodes also operate similarly to diodes, supplying current to the anode should be able to measure voltage on the cathode side as well.

But as you see upper Figure, cathode of the LD is not showing any voltage when FET is off-state.
It is like a opened-circuit.

Is it the right working situation ?

Edit)
DATASHEET : https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-6120373/SPL%20UL90AT08_EN.pdf

FET DRIVER BOARD User Guide : https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sluuc20

As shown in the graph on page 15 of Ti's User Guide, when measuring the cathode side with a probe, the signal should move.
Not at all

Comment: A data sheet link to the laser is needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "not showing any voltage"?   Your scope seems to be, though it's hard to tell with the tiny picture.  It's also not really clear what you are hoping to accomplish by these measurements... controlling a laser diode current is a tricky problem hopefully encapsulated in some already proven circuit, while LIDAR tends to require *extreme* time agility...

Comment: DATASHEET : https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-6120373/SPL%20UL90AT08_EN.pdf

Comment: I wonder if the laser diode works.
When a general diode is applied to the anode with a voltage exceeding Vf, for example, the voltage can be detected even on the cathode side also. Of course, it is assumed that the cathode side is connected to a high-impedance load without current flowing to the ground. It should be the same in the case of laser diodes, but it was not. I heard that the laser diode should be current-driving, and apart from that, it must be able to carry current for voltages exceeding Vf. However, it is observed that the laser diode now operates like a broken circuit.

Comment: You have still failed to explain what you mean by "not showing any voltage" as in your plot it sure seems to be.  But anyway, your drawn circuit seems rather inappropriate, there's no feedback to control the current so you seem to get only the open-loop gain of the FET.  Maybe you already ruined it.  If not, consider putting a small sense resistor in so you can at least measure current.  And get a more suitable driving circuit...